# Which iOS target do I need to set to avoid bundling Swift runtime libraries with my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

Reading the [Evolving Swift On Apple Platforms After ABI Stability](https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-apple/), Swift 5 introduces **ABI stability**, and one benefit is:

> Most obviously, applications written in Swift no longer need to be distributed with the Swift runtime libraries, reducing download size.

Which iOS target do I need to set to avoid bundling Swift runtime with my iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **iOS 12.2**.

Source : [Xcode 10.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/swift-5-release-notes-for-xcode-10_2)

Interesting part is in **App Thinning** section.

> To see the difference in file sizes between an app that’s thinned for iOS 12.2 and an app that’s thinned for iOS 12.1 or earlier, set your app’s deployment target to iOS 12.1 or earlier, then create an archive of your app with the scheme set to Generic iOS Device. After building the archive, select Distribute App from the Archives organizer, then select Development distribution. Be sure to select a specific device—such as iPhone XS—in the App Thinning pull-down menu. When the distribution process completes, open the App Thinning Size Report in the newly created folder. The variant for iOS 12.2 will be smaller than the variant for iOS 12.1 and earlier. The exact size difference depends on the number of system frameworks your app uses.